# Show that $SO(2,\mathbb{R})_{\mathrm{finite}}$ and $(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}, \hat{+})$ are isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> 1. Let $G$ an abelian group and $G_{\mathrm{finite}} = \{g \in G : |g|<\infty\}$. Then $G_{\mathrm{finite}}$ is a subgroup of G. **(already
>      proved)**
> 2. Let $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ the set of equivalence classes under the relation $\sim$ defined as $\frac{p}{q} \sim \frac{r}{s} \iff
>     \exists n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\frac{p}{q} =  \frac{r}{s} + n$.
>      Then $\overline{\frac{p}{q}} \hat{+} \overline{\frac{r}{s}} :=
>    \overline{\frac{p}{q} \hat{+} \frac{r}{s}}$ is a well-defined
>      operation on $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ and $(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z},
>     \hat{+})$ is a group. **(already proved)**
> 3. Let $SO(2,\mathbb{R})$ the group of orthogonal matrices $2 \times 2$ of determinant $1$. Show that $SO(2,\mathbb{R})_{\mathrm{finite}}$ and
>      $(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}, \hat{+})$ are isomorphics.

The number 3. is causing me problems. I don't want to give me the answer to this problem. I just want someone to give me a hint how to start. Is someone able to do this?

Comment: What do you know about the group $SO(2,\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: if $A= 2 \times 2~matrix
\[ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b \\
c & d \\
 \end{array} \right)\] \in SO(2,\mathbb{R})$, then there exist $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $A^n=1$ (according to 1.), $det(A)=1$ and $A^T A = I$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Show that a matrix is in $SO(2,\mathbb{R})$ if and only if it is of the form $R(\theta)=\begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{pmatrix}$ for some $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$ (geometrically, this is a rotation by an angle of $\theta$).  Show furthermore that multiplication of matrices of this form corresponds to addition of angles: that is, $R(\theta)R(\theta')=R(\theta+\theta')$.  Now think about what it means for $R(\theta)$ to have order $n$.